# How to create a fixed length tf.Dataset from generator?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a generator which yields infinite amount of data (Random image crops). I would like to create a `tf.Dataset` based on let's say 10,000 first data points and cache it to use them to train models?

Currently, I have a generator which takes 1-2 seconds to create each datapoint and this is the main performance blocker. I have to wait a minute to generate a batch of 64 images (the `preprocessing()` function is very expensive, so I would like to reuse the results).

`ds = tf.Dataset.from_generator()` method allows us to create such infinite dataset. Instead, I would like to create a finite dataset using N first outputs from the generator and cache it like:

`ds = ds.cache()`.

---

Alternative solution is to keep generating new data, and using cached datapoints while rendering the generator.

Comment: In this case I would run a separate tf session creating your inputs in batchsize=1 and storing them to disk. And having a separate training session reading the cache folder and feeding to the model. The only thing, i dont think there is a straightforward way of making your dataset to know about new inputs after initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Dataset.cache` function with the `Dataset.take` function to accomplish this.

If everything fits in memory its as simple as doing something like this:

```py
def generate_example():
  i = 0
  while(True):
    print ('yielding value {}'.format(i))
    yield tf.random.uniform((64,64,3))
    i +=1

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generate_example, tf.float32)

first_n_datapoints = ds.take(n).cache()
```

Now note, that if I set `n` to 3 say then do something trivial like:

```py
for i in first_n_datapoints.repeat():
  print ('')
  print (i.shape)
```

then I see output confirming that the first 3 values are cached (I only see the `yielding value {i}` output once for each of the first 3 values generated:

```
yielding value 0
(64,64,3)
yielding value 1
(64,64,3)
yielding value 2
(64,64,3)
(64,64,3)
(64,64,3)
(64,64,3)
...
```

If everything does not fit in memory then we can pass a filepath to the cache function where it will cache the generated tensors to disk.

More info here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache

Comment: For the record, I get the warning that: The calling iterator did not fully read the dataset being cached. In order to avoid unexpected truncation of the dataset, the partially cached contents of the dataset will be discarded. This can happen if you have an input pipeline similar to `dataset.cache().take(k).repeat()`. You should use `dataset.take(k).cache().repeat()` instead.

Comment: I don't actually know why I get it since I follow exactly the structure the warning asks for. Also, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Hmm - curious. I didn't see that warning when verifying my toy example above. I guess if its working its working but that is odd :-/